# Rotate Bitmap on Android Canvas

Tags: android

I have some objects which I draw onto a Canvas as part of a SurfaceView. I want to be able to rotate these programmatically, e.g. `myParticle.setRotation(90);` Here's my (simplified) code to draw the Particle at the moment:

```
public class Particle {

  public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    image.setBounds((int)(xPos), (int)(yPos), (int)(xPos+radius), (int)(yPos+radius));
    image.draw(canvas);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to call

`canvas.rotate(90) :)   // 90 is degree.`

Comment: And canvas.rotate(0) afterwards!

Comment: canvas.save() and canvas.restore() is more efficient.

Comment: but it rotates all the objects on the canvas. I want to rotate only one. actually they are animating images, so are getting called in a thread.

Comment: This is old but let me answer, if you apply this approach you are rotating canvas not picture, so canvas.save before and canvas.restore after drawing bitmap will restore your canvas to old position, you can apply it on a single bitmap, by storing the list of bitmaps and apply rotate only when you found that index of bitmap with the help of loop which you want to draw.

Answer (score 60):

To me it seems cleaner to do this:

```
Matrix rotator = new Matrix();

// rotate around (0,0)
rotator.postRotate(90);

// or, rotate around x,y
// NOTE: coords in bitmap-space!
int xRotate = ...
int yRotate = ...
rotator.postRotate(90, xRotate, yRotate);

// to set the position in canvas where the bitmap should be drawn to;
// NOTE: coords in canvas-space!
int xTranslate = ...
int yTranslate = ...
rotator.postTranslate(xTranslate, yTranslate);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rotator, paint);
```

This way the canvas stays directed as before, and you can do more stuff with your matrix like translating, scaling etc. and the matrix's content encapsulates the real meaning of your manipulation.

**Edit**: Eddie wanted to know around which point the rotation happens.

**Edit**: AndrewOrobator wanted to know how to set the canvas destination coords

Comment: How do you specify X and Y values for the position with this method?

Comment: @Eddie: What do you mean by 'how do you specify'?

Comment: I think he means the position in which the bitmap will be displayed on the canvas

Comment: @AndrewOrobator Yes, i figured it out and edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: I still don't think it's clear. Using your method, what would be the x and y coordinates of the top left corner of the bitmap in relation to the canvas and is there a way to set it?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator "... what would be the x and y ... ": Well, the x and y coords for rotation are in bitmap-space and define the rotation point within the bitmap. If you want to set the position when drawing, you have to add postTranslate(x1,y1), where x1,y1 are in canvas-space. i will edit my post

Comment: Realistically this is THE answer to the question. The accepted answer explains how to rotate the canvas and not how to rotate the bitmap on the Android canvas.

Comment: can I re-use this matrix object when drawing several bitmaps, as long as I call postRotate+postTranslate every time?