# resize and rotate layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, resize

[image]

can anyone guide in how to do this layout ?? i'm trying to figure out how the developer figure out to rotate and resize the layout on the touch event, would anyone give me an example or guide in how to do it. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{       

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int X = (int)event.getX();          
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        ...Rotate the image
    }
}
```

For more info check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593211/resize-image-while-rotating-image-in-android) .Hope it may help you!!

Comment: i'v used MyGestureDetector before to rotate an image , but how to resize the layout / image . this is my main problem that i can't figure it out.

Comment: @Kosh check the link that i have added it shows how to resize also

Comment: +1 for helping me ,
i'v saw the question but there is no strict answer to what i'm looking for. thanks for your help

Comment: @Kosh its fine..if you need automatic resize then you can use android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: i know about that , all i want is to know how to do that manually by using touch event, i'v created the rotation , but the problem is how to resize the layout especially if you see the picture it contains text not image.