# how to create a bubbles game UI in android

Tags: android-animation, android

I want to create a bubbles like game in android and I'm not sure how to draw the graphics.
Should I use canvas ? Every bubble should be a bitmap or maybe an image view ?

Another thing, I want to be able to rotate / scale the bubbles.
I've tried with bitmaps and canvas but wasn't able to rotate the bubbles.
Image view for every bubble looks like a mess to me.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a game, I would suggest using a Canvas, and put the Canvas over most, or all, of your layout. Creating anything but the most basic game using the regular UI structures would be a nightmare.

It sounds like you've gotten to the point where you can load the bubble images and draw them to the canvas, which is good. As for rotating the bubbles, use this:

```
Matrix rotator = new Matrix();
rotator.postRotate(90);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rotator, paint);
```

That was from an answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601500/805819), which was more specifically about rotating bitmaps on a Canvas.

For more information on making games in Android, [this book](http://www.apress.com/9781430230427) was pretty helpful for me.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks or your help but I have a few more questions: do I need to create a matrix for every bitmap if I want that every bitmap will rotate in a different way ? do I need to place the code that you wrote in the inDraw function of my canvas ?