# How to Rotate an Arrow Drawable about it's Center

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an arrow drawable that I simply want to rotate without it moving either in the x or y direction.
To explain further, consider a ball spinning about a fixed point or the circular Android progressbar.
Additionally, the drawable will rotate -180 degree when clicked and 180 degress when clicked again.

Please, is there anyway this can be done programmatically?

**Update**
From Jason Wihardja's answer, I was able to achieve this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (v.getId() == imageButton.getId()) {
                int visibilty =newsBody.getVisibility();
                if (visibilty == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(180.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                    animation.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    animation.setDuration(300);
                    imageButton.startAnimation(animation);
                    newsBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 180.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                    animation.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    animation.setDuration(300);
                    imageButton.startAnimation(animation);
                    newsBody.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
```

But is there anyway I can avoid repeating the animation building? Like just build it once and toggle the degrees in each click.

Comment: use `android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable`

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496036/rotate-bitmap-on-android-canvas

Comment: @ user1676075 the arrow is a png file that resides in the res/drawable folder and I'm using it as the `src` for an ImageButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RotateAnimation` class to do that. Here's an example on how to do that

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(180.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(animationDuration);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
arrowImageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

To rotate in a different direction, just flip the angle parameters.

Comment: You could substitute the code with xml version. But even if you do so, you'll still have to build 2 anim files